# Attempting to Delete Record from MySQL Database + PHP. But Keep Getting Error message

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to delete a row by using a DELETE statement. However, since I am new to PHP, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code keeps echoing an error message and I don't know how to get it to work.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>peak | delete student</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 300px;">
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="student_number" placeholder="student number" 
id="student number"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
</div>

<?php 

include 'config.php';

$id = ''; 
if( isset( $_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id']; 
} 

    if(isset($_POST["student_number"])) {

    $sql= "DELETE FROM `Students` (`first name`,`last name`,`student 
number`,`gender`,`address`,`phone number`,`mark`) WHERE `student number`='".$id."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result){echo "student deleted successfully!";}

    else {echo "error. unable to delete student.";}

    }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is the error message? plus your code is vulnerable to SQL injection!

Comment: What @MehdiBounya says, and not just a bit. This would mean a simple URL modification in the address bar empties your Students table.

Comment: Take out the column list in your DELETE query. `DELETE FROM Students WHERE ....`

Comment: that isn't how DELETE works, it's not like an INSERT/UPDATE which you seem to be getting mixed up with.

Comment: and Lord only knows why you're using `$_GET['id']` and where that is coming from. I'm not touching this.

Comment: @jhilgeman could you elaborate a bit more? sorry, i'm new to this

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i'm using id because it's required by my school teacher. And also because this page is linked to another table where there are multiple users, it's so my teacher knows which person from the table she's dealing with

Comment: @MehdiBounya The error message is "error. unable to add student" and I'm aware. When my code works, I'll be doing the injections etc.

Comment: What is @FunkFortyNiner saying is, anyone can delete a record just by supplying the ID at the end of the URL, more details [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Comment: basic syntax is this: `DELETE FROM table WHERE x=y`

Comment: *"The error message is "error. unable to add student""* - Huh, where's that? Question's unclear here and I gave you the basic syntax to delete. You will need to do this yourself if  you want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the record by using this way. here, no need to include field name in delete query.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if(!$con)
die("could not connect:".mysqli_error());
else
echo "connected<br>";

if(isset($_GET["student_number"])) 
{
$id = $_GET["student_number"]; 

    $sel="select * from students where student_number='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sel);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $checkid=$row['student_number'];

    if($id==$checkid)
    {
    $sql="delete from students where student_number='$id'";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($result)
    {
    echo "student deleted successfully!";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "error. unable to delete student.";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "no record found";
}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>peak | delete student</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <form method="get" action="">
            <input type="text" name="student_number" placeholder="student number" 
            id="student number"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
        </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to delete. I was using id and post so i removed the id method and only used post

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<title>peak | delete student</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left: 300px;">
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="student_number" placeholder="student number" 
id="student number"><br>
<input type="submit" value="delete">
</form>
</div>

<?php 

 include 'config.php';


    if(isset($_POST["student_number"])) {

    $sql= "DELETE FROM `Students` WHERE `student number`=".$_POST["student_number"];

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if($result){echo "success!";}

    else {echo "error.";}

    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```